# Returning a boolean value

Tags: boolean

Say I have a car that has a certain amount of gas in it and if it gets below:

```
public static final double TESTCLASS = 0.000001;
```

then it is empty.

How do I represent this with something like this:

```
public boolean isEmpty(){

}
```

I've tried doing just this (below), but I get an error with the "<"

```
public boolean isEmpty(){
    gas < TESTCLASS;
}
```

Comment: return gas < TESTCLASS;

Comment: you forgot the keyword `return`

Comment: Why is the threshold named `TESTCLASS`? Is `isEmpty` defined in the same class as `gas`? What type is `gas`?

Comment: mind that comparison of doubles is not always safe, look: http://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/

Answer (score 1):

You've missed out the `return` statement.

```
public boolean isEmpty(){
    return (gas < TESTCLASS);
}
```

Putting the Boolean expression in parentheses makes sure it is evaluated as a Boolean - not sure if you really need it in this case though.

PS: It's a good idea to name your variables semantically - so TESTCLASS would be better as "gasLimit" or "emptyGas"

Comment: Even as what I have below it tells me "<" is an invalid assignment operator:    public boolean isEmpty(){
  gas < EPSILON;
  return true;
 }

Comment: Use the exact code I typed. Unless of course your variable is called EPSILON, in which case change that bit.

Comment: If I put what you said to put, will it return that the gas tank is empty? Sorry - very new to Java and REALLY appreciate the help!

Comment: Yep - it's fine, everyone has to learn! This will return true if the tank is empty.